# Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation

My java(1.7) project handles xml files. However, for one particular xml file it gives following exception in DEV environment but not in SIT environment. Project runs on WebLogic 12.1.2 in both environments. This exception does not throw when I remove double quotes in DEV. But I’m wondering why it doesn’t throw exception in SIT without removing double quotes.

XML tag like this:

```xml
<abc>xxx “yyyyyy” xxxxxxx<\abc>
```

```
Exception throws: java.io.CharConversionException: Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported: bytes 0x93 implies a length of more than 4 bytes 
at .org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.UTF8XMLDecoder.decode(UTF8XMLDecoder.java:162)
```

Can anybody guide me which areas I need to look at ?

Comment: Did you mean `</abc>`, not `<\abc>`?

Comment: The error is not specifically about the quotes, but about invalid UTF-8 encoded text. Or rather, it's about the fact that the XML parser decodes using UTF-8 unless otherwise explicitly told to use another encoding, and that byte `0x93` is invalid in **UTF-8**, but happens to be character `“` in character set [**Windows-1252**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set), which means that the *file is incorrectly encoded*, or the *code is incorrectly parsing the file*.

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks for the feedback. It should be </abc>.(typography)

Comment: So what do you suggest me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Encoding errors should always be fixed at source if at all possible. Find out where the encoding error came from and fix the component that generated the bad data. Repairing the damage downstream is much harder, and can only be done if you have a very precise understanding of the exact nature of the miscoding.

Comment: Best solution is to ensure that XML is always encoded in UTF-8, so whatever process created the file should be fixed to do that. Alternatively, the process should make sure to specify the actual encoding in the XML prolog, e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>`, and the code parsing the XML should honor that.